# Using pymongo, how do you find all documents, such that an embedded list in each document contains greater than X elements?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I would like to run a find-query on MongoDB that searches over a set of documents in a collection, where each document contains a list of elements, and only return the documents in which the # of elements in the list is greater than X.

This returns all documents where len(messages) == X:

```
db.log.find({'messages':{'$size':X}})
```

but how do I get all documents where len(messages) >= X ?

Comment: there is no operator for that.  You would have to keep track yourself by incrementing another field in the document on each $push if you want to be able to query like this.

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/size/

Comment: you can use aggregation framework if it doesn't have to be super fast - find is always going to be quicker though.

Comment: Could you please sketch the solution via the aggregation framework, I'm still new to that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in aggregation framework via this pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate({$unwind:"$messages"},
                        {$group:{_id:"$_id", msgCount:{$sum:1}}},
                        {$match:{msgCount:{$gte:<SIZE>}}}
);
```

Fill in the size you are looking for exceed for `<SIZE>`.

Comment: $size is basically doing a summation, yes.

Answer (score 2):

In MongoDB 2.2+ you can take advantage of the fact that you can use numeric array indexes in query object keys to do this:

```
# X is the minimum number of messages
X = 3
db.log.find({'messages.' + str(X-1): {'$exists': 1}})
```

Comment: I like this answer too, just wondering if this is faster than using the aggregation framework directly (?)

Comment: @vgoklani This should be much faster, and you get the original document, not the unwound and grouped one.

Comment: Certainly this will be at least as efficient as equality on $size - neither can use an index, and it should be faster than aggregation framework, though I don't have a data set large enough to show a significant difference, I'm getting about the same performance on medium size dataset.

Comment: however, on a quick test, this method seems 4-5x slower than $size operator for equality, which surprises me - I would have thought they would take about the same amount of time) and aggregate seems to be more comparable to $size.

Comment: looks like the array index method is disproportionately paying some performance penalty when the index (size being tested) gets larger.  Probably something that can be fixed.